# How to render text with clickable hyperlinks where you can control the action for click?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I'm tryiing to display some text in my app where there might be some URL in the text. I want the URL to be highlighted as hyperlinks and clickable. Furthermore, when it is clicked, I want to supply a callback where I can perform custom action. Of course the URL should be passed back to my callback so I know what to do with it (say open it in an in-app browser etc).

This might sound complicated but basically all the IM apps in the appstore (over 30 of them) have this functionality where a user can send an IM containing a URL and the receiving end can click on it and open the page in an in-app browser.

How is this done? I just can't figure it out. If you have a solution, please provide **sample code.** Thank you.

---

**BTW:**

The answer is **NOT A UIWebView** (because it is very slow to render multiple instances of it).

The answer is also **NOT A UITextView** because although it is capable of parsing URL it cannot be set a custom callback on clicks. So it just ends up opening safari.

The answer is also **NOT A TTStyledTextLabel** because although it is capable of parsing URL and assigning a custom action to it, it needs to be pre-assigned in a URLMap. And obviously in this case we don't know what the URL is before hand. As far as I know you cannot assign ALL url to a custom action.

[alt text http://img169.yfrog.com/img169/3373/picture1ufx.png](http://img169.yfrog.com/img169/3373/picture1ufx.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As far as I know you cannot assign ALL url to a custom action.

I gave you directions in your [other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1172070/just-how-to-you-use-ttstyledtextlabel), so I'm a bit puzzled as to why you haven't read the source I linked to because it answered this *exact* question. `TTURLMap` supports catch-alls via the "`-from:toViewController:selector`" method. For example:

```
[map from:@"*" toViewController:[ViewController class]
        selector:@selector(someHandler:)];
```

I'd understand the confusion if you were dealing with a complete undocumented library, but the Three20 library is *very* well documented to the point of including sample applications that do exactly what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

> This might sound complicated but basically all the IM apps in the appstore (over 30 of them) have this functionality where a user can send an IM containing a URL and the receiving end can click on it and open the page in an in-app browser.

Yet what you want are custom callbacks, so this is a different functionality. They may be using UITextViews.

You'll probably have to write the code yourself, e.g. text rendering and link detection, or modify TTStyledTextLabel (which, in either case, looks like a good place to start). I do something similar and I just create UIButtons over any links. For link detection code check out Adium's source.