# Can I access views when drawn in the drawRect method?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview, core-graphics, drawrect

When creating the content view of a tableViewCell, I used the drawInRect:withFont, drawAtPoint... and others, inside drawRect: since all I needed was to lay some text. Turns out, part of the text drawn need to be clickable URLs. So I decided to create a UIWebView and insert it into my drawRect. Everything seems to be laid out fine, the problem is that interaction with the UIWebView is not happening. I tried enabling the interaction, did not work. I want to know, since with drawRect: I am drawing to the current graphics context, there is anything I can do to have my subviews interact with the user?
here is some of my code I use inside the UITableViewCell class.

```
-(void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect{  
    NSString *comment = @"something";
    [comment drawAtPoint:point forWidth:195 withFont:someFont lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeMiddleTruncation];

    NSString *anotherCommentWithURL = @"this comment has a URL http://twtr.us";
    UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:someFrame];
    webView.delegate = self;
    webView.text = anotherCommentWithURL;
    [self addSubView:webView];
    [webView release];
}
```

As I said, the view draws fine, but there is no interaction with the webView from the outside. the URL gets embedded into HTML and should be clickable. It is not. I got it working on another view, but on that one I lay the views.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do **not** want to be creating a new `UIWebView` and adding it as a subview for each call to `drawRect:` This is an **extremely** bad idea:

1. It's going to be slow. Those are heavy objects, and you're creating thousands of them.
2. You're not getting rid of the old `UIWebView` objects. So you're essentially layering thousands and thousands of them on top of one another.

You should be creating the `UIWebView` *once*, probably in the initializer, or some other method that is only called once. You should also add it as a subview only once.

The act of creating thousands of those views could certainly be causing your problem.

If your view is changing position/size, then you can override `setFrame:` and in addition to calling the superclass' method, tweak the frame of the `UIWebView`, which you'll definitely want to maintain as an instance variable.

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong. You shouldn't be instantiating UIWebView inside -drawRect: - which is, potentially, called repeatedly to refresh screen.

Instead, you should at least create a subclass of UITableViewCell and add to it a UIWebView to hold all of your text.

Even then, UIWebView is probably too heavyweight to be placed in each cell.

You might want to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185476/how-to-render-text-with-clickable-hyperlinks-where-you-can-control-the-action-for) out.