# how to set Image using NSAttributedString

Tags: iphone

Can i set image to corresponding substring using NSAttributedString.If yes,how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The NSAttributedString used by the Core Text engine only supports formatting text. You need to use 3rd-party rendering code if you need to embed an image, e.g. [TTStyledTextLabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1172070/just-how-to-you-use-ttstyledtextlabel).